# Flutter SQFLite Database

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I have been trying to write an app using flutter. The app has the functionality of login/sign-up like all basic apps. For this, I am using an API link and the response I am getting is in JSON format. The response has data like the user id, name, age, etc. I want to store this data in a local database on the device so that I can use this data to display some information and logging in to the account without requiring the user to enter the details again and again. I have been trying various ways to achieve this but am unable to do it. I have followed the official documentation of sqflite but have not been able to run it successfully. I am really looking forward to any help that I can get.

Thank you in advance. If you require any data/code, Please let me know and I will post the same.

Answer (score 0):

1.implement this following dependency on pubspec.yaml

```
 sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
(dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3)
```

2.create model class

```
class Student {
  int id;
  String name;
  Student(this.id, this.name);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
    return map;
  }

  Student.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
  }
}
```

3.create dbhelper class

```
import 'package:flutter_sqlite_crud/student_model.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;
  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDatabase();
    return _db;
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, 'student.db');
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db
        .execute('CREATE TABLE student (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)');
  }

  Future<Student> add(Student student) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    student.id = await dbClient.insert('student', student.toMap());
    return student;
  }

  Future<List<Student>> getStudents() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query('student', columns: ['id', 'name']);
    List<Student> students = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        students.add(Student.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return students;
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete(
      'student',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future<int> update(Student student) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update(
      'student',
      student.toMap(),
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [student.id],
    );
  }

  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

4.make UI design class create....